# Extract documentation link from Python help() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

Python has a built-in function called `help()` which returns the docstrings on methods or functions, per the [turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html). For example, say I was to type this:

```
>>> help('os')
```

I get greeted with

```
Help on module os:

NAME
    os - OS routines for NT or Posix depending on what system we're on.

MODULE REFERENCE
    https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os

    The following documentation is automatically generated from the Python
    source files.  It may be incomplete, incorrect or include features that
    are considered implementation detail and may vary between Python
    implementations.  When in doubt, consult the module reference at the
    location listed above.

. . .
```

and so forth. It is quite simple to find the module reference by just looking at this, but say I was collecting the references to 100 different modules. It would take quite some time and would be very repetitive work.

How can I parse through each `help()` function for the link to the module's documentation? It would involve finding a similar value such as `https://` or `.org` or `.com`.

Comment: Does the URL always occur immediately after `MODULE REFERENCE`?

Comment: Sometimes, but not always. @MateenUlhaq

Comment: I suppose it's reasonable to assume that the URL occurs within the first dozen lines (or the last dozen lines). It's also reasonable to assume that it's the first URL that we're looking for. All the `python` module URLs are of the form `https://docs.python.org/3(.8)?/library/<name>`, and I suppose the remaining URLs involve a PyPI or a github repo.

Comment: A few modules have a link to their own site and several have the URL at the foot of the output. But 99% of the time it is the first and only URL found.

Comment: I think the best way to discover a reasonably reliable method is to start by listing all URLs for a module, for every module, at the line they occur. See if there's any patterns (e.g. if no URL in first dozen lines, it's probably the final URL at the footer). And rank them based on likelihood (shorter URLs are better, URLs that follow known formats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that you actually don't need to do any parsing, since as far as I know, all the standard library Python modules have documentation accessible at the URL `https://docs.python.org/<version>/library/<modulename>`. It would be *far* more efficient to construct the URL according to that pattern compared to parsing the help text.

That being said, if you really do want to parse the help text, [the `re.search` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) should be useful. You can write a regular expression to match the URL of a Python standard library documentation page and presumably the first match should be the result you want.